# How to make a ROS publish/subscribe unit test deterministic?

Tags: c++, ros

I create a publisher and a subscriber, publish a message, then check if the callback has fired. The check actually fails unless I spin for some hundreds of cycles after publishing. How do I make the unit test deterministic?

```cpp
bool called_back = false;
Publisher  p = node.advertise(topic, 1);
Subscriber s = node.subscribe(topic, 1, [&]{ called_back = true; })

p.publish();
for (int i = 0; i != 1000; ++i)
  ros::spinOnce();
ASSERT_TRUE(called_back);
```

Comment: Preferably, you should make your code as independent from the library as possible. If you can inject dependency and mock the behaviour of the library, you are in control - full deterministic option.

Comment: Check out waiting for a message: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/melodic-devel/clients/rospy/src/rospy/client.py#L391

Comment: In ros, the best design is to separate as much of the real code into it's own class/library, then just have a ros node as boilerplate around it, calling the class/library interface and translating its IO into/from ros msgs to/from other nodes. 
This will reduce testing to testing the (normal) c++/python code, and then the node itself. As for the node, if you rosbag record the inputs to it, you can make a [test launch file](https://wiki.ros.org/rostest) to assert on the outputs, for a given constant/consistent input. In this way, you can test each node, and, if you need to/want to, scale up.

Comment: @JWCS How do you assure the whole launch file did not kill the rosbag earlier than the message arrived to it?

Comment: The rosbag playback parameters can be set to looping, or to end at end of file; to play the msgs as fast as possible, or at the times recorded. While the node processes spawn in the order listed in the launch file, the time difference should be minuscule, but placing the rosbag play last will make it start after the rest of the nodes. The rostest platform is for _unit tests_, which should be << 1 sec; if you need long-running tests, don't use rostest, write your own testing launch files.